# Function to check if a string contains uppercase characters?

Tags: sql-server-2014, sql-function

I need to create a SQL Server function to check if an input string contains any uppercase characters. If yes then it should return "OK". If no It should return "NOT OKAY".

When the below statements are executed, it should return the expected values as below.

```
PRINT dbo.CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK('abc') -- Expected: "NOT OK"
PRINT dbo.CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK('ABC') -- Expected: "OK"
```

this is what i tried, but i do not know to specify the return values as mentioned above.

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK (@String varchar(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
Declare @KeepValues as varchar(50)
Set @KeepValues = '%[^ ][A-Z]%'

While PatIndex(@KeepValues collate Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) > 0
    Set @Temp = Stuff(@Temp, PatIndex(@KeepValues collate   
  Latin1_General_Bin, @Temp) + 1, 0, ' ')

RETURN @Temp
```

END

Comment: Show us your current efforts! Where are you stuck? What is the problem you're facing?

Comment: What is `@Temp` ?? It's not defined anywhere - neither as parameter, nor as local variable ...

Comment: the expected return values should be assigned to @temp

Answer (score 5):

How about this? I just simply compare the `@String` parameter to a (simplified) pattern that checks for an uppercase character - and based on that index, I define the return values and return the appropriate response:

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK(@String varchar(MAX))
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @UpperCasePos BIGINT

    SELECT @UpperCasePos = PATINDEX('%[A-Z]%' collate Latin1_General_Bin, @String)

    DECLARE @Response VARCHAR(6)

    IF @UpperCasePos > 0
        SET @Response = 'OK'
    ELSE
        SET @Response = 'NOT OK'

    RETURN @Response
END
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to know if the string contains at least one upper-case character, why not do a case-sensitive comparison with the lower-caser version of the string?

```
CREATE FUNCTION CheckStringOfUpperAlphaOK 
(
    @STR VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(6)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN CASE 
             WHEN @STR = LOWER(@STR) COLLATE Latin1_General_Bin THEN 'NOT OK' 
             ELSE 'OK' 
           END
END
;
```